# How to test the side effects of a subscription in an Angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test, angular-observable

I have an Angular component, **MyComponent**, which calls a method returning an Observable and subscribes to it, something like

```
export class MyComponent {
  someProperty;
  constructor(service: MyService) {}
  someButtonClicked() {
    this.service.doStuffAsync().subscribe(
      resp => this.someProperty = resp;
    );
  }
}

@Injectable()
export MyService {
  doStuffAsync() {
    // returns an Observable which notifies asychronously, e.g. like HttoClient.get(url)
  }
}
```

I want to test the method `someButtonClicked()` and therefore I create a **MyServiceMock** class which I inject in the test

```
export class MyServiceMock {
  doStuffAsync() {
    return of({// some object}).pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler));
  }
}
```

For whatever reason I want `doStuffAsync()` of **MyServiceMock** to be asynchronous so `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` is used.

At this point though I do not know how to test `someButtonClicked()`. I have tried different strategies, e.g. the following

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceMock },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let component: MyComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  it('test someButtonClicked', async(() => {
    component.someButtonClicked();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.someProperty).toBeDefined();
    });
  }));
```

but this fails since `doStuffAsync()` of **MyServiceMock** asynchronous.

So my question is which is the best strategy to test the side effects (i.e. `someProperty` being set correctly) induced by a method which subscribes to an asynchronous Observable.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 // All code should be synchronous within this it block
    it('test someButtonClicked', async(() => {
      // sync - button clicks are synchronous
      component.someButtonClicked();

      // but after btn clicks, we need to let some async code to finish
      // like rxjs subscriptions etc.
      await fixture.whenStable();
      // and then continue

      expect(component.someProperty).toBeDefined();
    }));
```

Don't use then `fixture.whenStable().then()`

Answer (score 1):

I use a helper function called emitted

```
export const emitted = obs$ => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  const emitted$ = new Subject();
  obs$.pipe(takeUntil(emitted$)).subscribe(
    _ => {
      emitted$.next();
      emitted$.complete();
      resolve(true);
    },
    _ => {
      emitted$.next();
      emitted$.complete();
      reject('An error occurred');
    }
  )
});
```

If your mock services shared the same instance of the observable with the component

```
export class MyServiceMock {
  private obs$ = of({// some object}).pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler));

  doStuffAsync() {
    return obs$;
  }
}
```

inside your spec you can await it to have emitted

```
it('test someButtonClicked', async(async () => {
  component.someButtonClicked();
  const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  await emitted(service.doStuffAsync());
  expect(component.someProperty).toBeDefined();
}));
```

Seeing you subscribed to the same instance of the observable as the component you know the component has run it's observer function as well as you subscribed after the component did.